# converting a list with cubed defined function on python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, defined

I have created a range list - [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

```
    RangeList = list(range(2,11,2))
    RangeList

   [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I need to convert this list into [8, 64, 216, 512, 1000]
The criteria i am working with:

-use a for loop and the 'cubed' function defined to convert the above list to

-[8, 64, 216, 512, 1000]

```
def cubed(x):
y = x**3
print('  %s'%(y))
return(y)

for x in RangeList:
cubed(x)

 8
64
216
512
1000
```

What am i missing in my code to get this to present as a straight list with commas.

Comment: `results_list = [x**3 for x in RangeList]`

Comment: I tried this and it still presents int the same way

Comment: Don't print `results_list` item by item, just use `print(results_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the for loop with

```
RangeList = list(range(2,11,2))
CubedList = [x**3 for x in RangeList]
CubedList
```

Comment: that seems to return the same result

Comment: Here's a modified version, as someone said, you are printing off within the cubed function, so it is printing off each iteration as opposed to the final list.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list and append to the list one by one using for loop
like this:

```
l=[]
for x in RangeList:
    l.append(cubed(x))
print(l)
```

or, you can use list comprehension.

```
l = [cubed(x) for x in RangeList]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an empty list before your loop. And use .append().
Or you can use the list comprehension like in the comment.

```
RangeList = list(range(2,11,2))
def cubed(x):
    y = x**3
    return(y)

newList = []
for x in RangeList:
   newList.append(cubed(x))
print(newList)
```